# KeycloakJS custom adapter : how to insert the token into keycloakjs instance

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-js

I'm trying to develop a custom adapter in my electron app that uses default browser so we could use an OTP physical key (not actually supported by electron).
[Source](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#custom-adapters)

I'm trying to do something like the existing cordova adapter (but this one is internal) : [Here](https://www.unpkg.com/browse/keycloak-js@23.0.6/dist/keycloak.mjs)

I've reached to open a new external browser window, handled the login process but I can't finalyze the process and give the keycloak code (or token) to the keycloakjs instance.

Here is an extract of my actual typescript code :

```
async function getToken(receivedUrl: string) {
  console.debug(`receivedUrl: ${receivedUrl}`);
  // Example received url: keycloak/#state=39dfb7d9-d852-48c7-9d70-c68c8f329f94&session_state=e31f41f7-ed60-4f50-95a5-5d97c3d97d5b&iss=https%3A%2F%2Fkeycloak.company.org%2Frealms%2Fmyrealm&code=653c0b53-7885-43e2-ab2c-15fb12d01224.e31f41f7-ed60-4f50-95a5-5d97c3d97d5b.a8500fbb-cd9a-4630-a3f6-0897cb3e1a37

  const parsedURl = new URL('https://fake.url/' + receivedUrl.replace('#', '?'));
  const code = parsedURl.searchParams.get('code');

  console.debug(`Received keycloak code = ${code}`);

  const tokenUrl = keycloak.authServerUrl! + '/realms/' + localConfig.KEYCLOAK_REALM + '/protocol/openid-connect/token';
  console.debug(`Getting token from url=${tokenUrl}`);

  const response = await axios.post(
    keycloak.authServerUrl!,
    {
      code: code,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: localConfig.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: localConfig.KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    }
  );
  console.debug('response', response);
  
  ///// ####### What to do HERE ?
  // keycloak.getToken(code);
  // keycloak.setToken();
}

let promiseResolve!: (value: void) => void;
let promiseReject!: (value: void) => void;
const customKeycloakPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  promiseResolve = resolve;
  promiseReject = reject;
});

const MyCustomAdapter: KeycloakAdapter = {
  login(options?: KeycloakLoginOptions) {
    shell.openExternal(keycloak.createLoginUrl(options)); // Open a new external browser window
    ipcRenderer.on('auth-success', (_event, url: string) => { // Manage to get the oauth2 url back
      getToken(url);
      promiseResolve();
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('auth-error', () => promiseReject());
    return customKeycloakPromise;
  },
  // ...
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

2nd question, would it be possible to have a keycloak.createTokenUrl() method to avoid the ugly concatenation (or have keycloak.endpoints exposed) ...

Related issue : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10174

Regards
Manuel